# Визуализация данных в таблице с помощью flet

Tags: python, flutter

Имеется двухмерный массив с данными из БД.
Подскажите, как отобразить всю полученную информацию в виде таблицы с помощью flet.
Заранее спасибо. P.s. Пробовал воспользоваться DataTable, а именно пытался загнать формирование строк в цикл, но безуспешно…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заполнение таблицы flet.DataTable данными из двухмерного массива:

```
table = ft.DataTable(
        columns=[
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("1")),
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("2")),
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("3"))      
                          
                                            
        ],
        
    )
for i in range(len(arr)):
    
    table.rows = table.rows  + [
            ft.DataRow(
                cells=[
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text(arr[i][0])),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text(arr[i][1])),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text(arr[i][2])),

                ],
            ),]
```